# Can't get android-inapp-billing-v3 library to initialize

Tags: java, android

I am currently implementing in-app purchases into my android application. I decided to use this library over here: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3.

I keep following the documentation but I can't see to get the billing processor to initialize. This is my code:

```
bp = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(this, "TESTING LICENSE", this); // doesn't bind
bp.initialize(); // binds
String result = bp.isInitialized() ? "YES" : "NO";
System.out.println(result); //Output: (String) "NO"
```

Has anyone that has used this library know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Inspect the error cause in `onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error)` callback. Log `error.getMessage()` and see the error cause.